# How to get the primary key of an Ms Access table in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, primary-key

I need the field or fields (just the name of the field will do) that form the primary key of a Microsoft Access Table, given a connection and a tableName.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, I guess I found it.  It should work for all oledb and is sth. like :

```
public static List<string> getKeyNames(String tableName, DbConnection conn)
    {
        var returnList = new List<string>();


        DataTable mySchema = (conn as OleDbConnection).
            GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys,
                                new Object[] {null, null, tableName});


        // following is a lengthy form of the number '3' :-)
        int columnOrdinalForName = mySchema.Columns["COLUMN_NAME"].Ordinal;

        foreach (DataRow r in mySchema.Rows)
        {
            returnList.Add(r.ItemArray[columnOrdinalForName].ToString());
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: You saved my day sooo much.
How does a solution so useful has no documented usage i can find is beyond me.