# VB.Net - How can I check if a primary key exists in an Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, primary-key, constraints

I want to check in an Access Database if a primary key exists using VB.Net & OleDb:

- By primary key name
- By number of fields as primary keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862749/how-to-get-the-primary-key-of-an-ms-access-table-in-c):

```
Public Shared Function getKeyNames(tableName As [String], conn As DbConnection) As List(Of String)
    Dim returnList = New List(Of String)()


    Dim mySchema As DataTable = TryCast(conn, OleDbConnection).GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys, New [Object]() {Nothing, Nothing, tableName})


    ' following is a lengthy form of the number '3' :-)
    Dim columnOrdinalForName As Integer = mySchema.Columns("COLUMN_NAME").Ordinal

    For Each r As DataRow In mySchema.Rows
        returnList.Add(r.ItemArray(columnOrdinalForName).ToString())
    Next

    Return returnList
End Function
```