# How to read column names using SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to read the column names from a table using a jet SQL query. The data table is held in ms-access in 2002-2003 compatibility mode. I have tried a couple of variations for the query but I can't seem to get the correct syntax.

```
DatabaseConnection("SELECT Column_name" & " FROM " & tablename, "Read Recordset")

DatabaseConnection("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = tabDataHourly", "read Recordset")
```

I have a function that runs the database connections:
     Public Function DatabaseConnection(ByVal Query As String, ByVal Task As String) As String
        'On Error GoTo Err

```
    cnnOLEDB = New OleDbConnection
    cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DataDirectoryName & DatabaseFileName
    cnnOLEDB.Open()

    cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB
    cmdOLEDB.CommandText = Query

    Select Case Task
        Case "Read Recordset"
            rdrOLEDB = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader()
            DatabaseConnection = "Read Recordset"
        Case "Read Scalar"
            DatabaseConnection = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteScalar
        Case "Non-Query"
            cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
            DatabaseConnection = "Non-Query"
    End Select

    Exit Function
Err:
    MsgBox("Database connection error.")
    DatabaseConnection = "Error"


End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If all you want is the name of a column, you can get ot from rdrOLEDB.GetName(0) where 0 is the column (field) number, otherwise you get the schema from the connection. Be aware that some connections return the wrong type for Memo. See here for a schema example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065086/vb-net-how-can-i-check-if-a-primary-key-exists-in-an-access-db

Comment: I would like all of the column names, the number of columns in the table will change so it can't be hard wired in.

Comment: You can run from i=0 to rdrOLEDB.FieldCount-1 I have added a note below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes on getting a field (column) name:

```
        Case "Read Recordset"
            rdrOLEDB = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader()
            DatabaseConnection = "Read Recordset"
            For i = 0 To rdrOLEDB.FieldCount - 1
                Console.Write(rdrOLEDB.GetName(i))
            Next
            Console.Read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_name,* from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'tabDataHourly'
order by ordinal_position
```

Comment: For this would I use `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery` or something else?

Comment: I very much doubt that there is any way you can make this work with MS Access.