# pyodbc - read primary keys from MS Access (MDB) database

Tags: python, sql, database, ms-access, pyodbc

When I try to use `cursor.primaryKeys("tablename")` then exception occurs:

`Error: ('IM001', '[IM001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLPrimaryKeys)')`

`list(cursor.columns(table='tablename'))` does not reveal primary keys either.

Comment: here is solution in .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862749/how-to-get-the-primary-key-of-an-ms-access-table-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Access ODBC we can usually<sup>*</sup> get the Primary Key columns via the [.statistics()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#statisticstable-catalognone-schemanone-uniquefalse-quicktrue) method of the pyodbc `cursor` object:

```py
crsr = conn.cursor()
table_name = 'MyTable'
# dict comprehension: {ordinal_position: col_name}
pk_cols = {row[7]: row[8] for row in crsr.statistics(table_name) if row[5]=='PrimaryKey'}
print(pk_cols)  # e.g., {1: 'InvID', 2: 'LineItem'}
```

<sup>*</sup>EDIT: This approach assumes that the primary key index for the table is named `PrimaryKey`. That is true if the table is created using the MS Access table builder (GUI) but is *not* true if the table is created using DDL (i.e., `CREATE TABLE …`). In those cases the primary key index will have a name like `Index_EA5344E1_0942_445C` so the above method won't work, but we can use ACE DAO instead:

```py
import win32com.client  # needs `pip install pywin32`


def get_access_primary_key_columns(db_path, table_name):
    db_engine = win32com.client.Dispatch("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    db = db_engine.OpenDatabase(db_path)
    tbd = db.TableDefs(table_name)
    for idx in tbd.Indexes:
        if idx.Primary:
            return [fld.Name for fld in idx.Fields]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        get_access_primary_key_columns(
            r"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb", "team"
        )
    )
    # ['city', 'prov']
```

Comment: what is the equivalent of `OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys` and `Columns["COLUMN_NAME"].Ordinal`? Right now you have hard-coded indices 5, 7, and 8 from statistics.

Comment: @denfromufa - Those are the column indices as defined in the documentation for the `.statistics` method of the [cursor object](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor). You could create your own variables, e.g., `ordinal_position_col = 7`, but aside from making the code a bit more self-documenting it would amount to the same thing.

Comment: actually it is defined by ODBC driver from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711022(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @denfromufa - Good reference. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution using pythonnet and Oledb Jet driver. Note that this does not preserve the order of primary keys as columns:

```
import clr
import System
import System.Data.OleDb
from System.Data.OleDb import OleDbSchemaGuid

def getKeyNames(tableName, mdbname):
    conn = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                         "Data source={}".format(mdbname))
    conn.Open()
    returnList=[]
    mySchema = (conn).GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys,
        [None, None, tableName])
    columnOrdinalForName = mySchema.Columns["COLUMN_NAME"].Ordinal
    for r in mySchema.Rows:
        returnList.append(r.ItemArray[columnOrdinalForName])
        conn.Close()
    return returnList

getKeyNames(table_name,mdbname)
```