# SQLAlchemy AutoMap AttributeError (despite having primary key defined)

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

I am trying to reflect an existing MS Access database into a new model. To link the database to SQLAlchemy, I am using

```
engine = create_engine("access+pyodbc://@db-dns")
```

Since the database already exists, I am following the basic use scheme from this article: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html

```
# reflect the table
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# mapped classes are now created with names by default
# matching that of the table name
Personen = Base.classes.ref_personen #here, 'ref_personen' is a table from my database

session = Session(engine)
```

When I try to access the table using `Personen.query.all()` I get an AttributeError (error log see below).

---

**EDIT:** To raise the error, I dont even have to query anything. I assume that the error is already caused at this line: `Personen = Base.classes.ref_personen`

---

Often, the reason for this error is due to not hanving defined a primary key in the external database. However, this is not the case for me. In my MS Access DB rel_personen table, a primary key is defined.

Thanks, I appreciate any help on this topic!

---

```
(appenv4) C:\Users\Code\webapps4>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py:919: SAWarning: The Access ODBC driver does not support the ODBC "SQLPrimaryKeys" function. get_pk_constraint() is returning an empty list.
  pk_cons = self.get_pk_constraint(
c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py:947: SAWarning: The Access ODBC driver does not support the ODBC "SQLForeignKeys" function. get_foreign_keys() is returning an empty list.
  fkeys = self.get_foreign_keys(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'ref_personen'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Code\webapps4\appenv4\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 990, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 596, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 845, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 321, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 346, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 406, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 273, in locate_app
    return find_best_app(script_info, module)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 68, in find_best_app
    app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 119, in call_factory
    return app_factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Code\webapps4\app\__init__.py", line 19, in create_app
    from .zkl import zkl as zkl_bp
  File "C:\Users\Code\webapps4\app\zkl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import zkl_forms, zkl_views
  File "C:\Users\Code\webapps4\app\zkl\zkl_views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .zkl_database import db_session, init_db
  File "C:\Users\Code\webapps4\app\zkl\zkl_database.py", line 12, in <module>
    Personen = Base.classes.ref_personen
  File "c:\users\code\webapps4\appenv4\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 188, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: ref_personen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) version 1.1.0 now supports reflection of Primary Key (PK) and Foreign Key (FK) constraints.

---

*(previous answer)*

As noted by one of the warning messages in your stack trace:

> SAWarning: The Access ODBC driver does not support the ODBC "SQLPrimaryKeys" function. get_pk_constraint() is returning an empty list.

This is a known issue with the Access ODBC driver. It is also discussed here

https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/issues/9

and here

[pyodbc - read primary keys from MS Access (MDB) database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37712307/2144390)

Comment: thank you for your reply! I really appreciate it. Given your apparent experience with databases and access in particular, would you recommend using a different database service than ms access in combination with sqlalchemy?

Comment: I made some tweaks to the dialect. Try `pip install git+https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access@dao_reflect` and see if that works any better.

Comment: thank you for your effort here. however, trying the updated version threw an ImportError back at me: 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Try doing `pip install pywin32`. (I added it as a dependency but maybe it didn't get installed.)

Comment: installing pywin32 did the trick for me. Thank you!